# Assign result of a command to a variable in declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm implementing declarative Jenkinsfile and I want to run windows command and assign the result to a variable.

Here is my code:

```
stage('check latest commit') {
    steps {
        script{
            COMMIT = bat("c:\\Software\\Git\\bin\\git.exe log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%%H'").trim() as String
            echo "${COMMIT}"
        }
    }
}
```

And I get the following log in the Jenkins job

```
c:\Software\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\TFS - XXX>c:\Software\Git\bin\git.exe log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%H' 
'656669102c187fe390a1e9d72ed47aa2d8528ad6'[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
```

So the command executes as expected and returns a hash for a latest commit in the HEAD. Great. However:

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method trim() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
```

at the end of the run, I get this error. This means that the value which is reuslt of the command is `null`, even though the command itself produces a result.

If I don't include a trim, like:

```
stage('check latest commit') {
    steps {
        script{
            COMMIT = bat("c:\\Software\\Git\\bin\\git.exe log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%%H'")
            echo "${COMMIT}"
        }
    }
}
```

following entry in the log shows:

```
[Pipeline] bat

c:\Software\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\TFS - XXX>c:\Software\Git\bin\git.exe log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%H' 
'c77c806cdafd4f45373ef0cef8c6ff60da26611f'[Pipeline] echo
null
[Pipeline] }
```

Notice the **NULL** value in the log. That is the result of me trying to print the value of COMMIT.

Question: 
How do I properly assign a value to a variable, when such value should return from the cmd command. I'm implementing declarative Jenkinsfile and I cannot turn back to scripted one now.

EDIT: Yes, I'm aware that I could get the commit hash in a different manner, however, there are other commands that I need to run and I need their values as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you execute `bat` step does not return any output.

```
COMMIT = bat("c:\\Software\\Git\\bin\\git.exe log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%%H'")
```

The default behavior returns `null` and prints the output to the console. If you want to capture the output, you need to set `returnStdout` parameter to `true`.

```
COMMIT = bat(script: "@c:\\Software\\Git\\bin\\git.exe log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%%H'", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

You can check [the official documentation page](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script) to learn more about all parameters the `bat` step supports.

Comment: There is one more thing neded. ReturnStdout will also return the entire command. In order to get the result only, @ needs to be present before the command, like so "@c:\\Software\\Git\\bin\\git.exe log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%%H'". Also calling trim() removes trailing new line. If you edit the answer, I'll mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the default behaviour of the bat step. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script

By default bat just prints to console. returnStdout will give you the value as you expect. It is already a string, no need to cast.

```
COMMIT = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "c:\\Software\\Git\\bin\\git.exe log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%%H'").trim()
```